# How to fix gyp-ERR ECONNRESET?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to build an angular project with yarn, but I always receive some errors.

```
Build failed with error code: 1"
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 72.30s.
```

Actually, this error occurs because the node-gyp fails:

```
c:\temp\helloworld>node-gyp configure
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.12.0 | win32 | x64
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-headers.tar.gz
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.12.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.12.0/win-x64/node.lib
gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.12.0/win-x86/node.lib
gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v8.12.0/SHASUMS256.txt
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:622:25)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\matyig\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Data\\global\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\temp\helloworld
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok

c:\temp\helloworld>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node-gyp is executing scripts by downloading them. It seems the internet connection is not stable which is why the script download is being stopped in between. SOme files are really large and needs to be downloaded like SHASUMS256.txt. Please try to run the command on a stable internet connection.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I am connected to internet behind a corporate proxy.
Is there any way to perform it manually? f.e. download the files and copy somewhere..?

Comment: I am not really sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally occurs when a corporate firewall is there and to resolve this you can add custom values of registry, proxy and https-proxy to your .npmrc file to fix this.

Example:

```
registry=http://companyname.com/artifactory/api/npm/npm/
proxy=http://username:password@proxy.companyname.com:80
https-proxy=http://username:password@proxy.companyname.com:80
```